# Best way to write integration tests in React with Redux and Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, integration-testing, enzyme

I'm trying to write some integrations tests in my application.

I have a couple API calls, that's called on componentDidMount and on button click. The API response it's saved on Store, which update the view.

How can I test this integration with the API?

This is my WIP code:

```
    let wrapped

    const options = {
        disableLifecycleMethods: true 
    }

    const mockPlanet = {
        name: "Yavin IV",
        climate: "temperate, tropical",
        terrain: "jungle, rainforests",
        population: "1000",
        films: ["A New Hope"],
        url: "https://swapi.co/api/planets/3/"
    }

    const initialPlanet = {
        name: "Alderaan",
        climate: "temperate",
        terrain: "grasslands, mountains",
        population: "2000000000",
        films: ["A New Hope", "Revenge of the Sith"],
        url: "https://swapi.co/api/planets/2/"
    }

    const mockStore = configureMockStore([thunk])

    const store = mockStore({
        planets:{    
            planetCount: 1,
            activePlanet: initialPlanet,
            planetCache: [],
            loading: false,
            error: null
        }        
    })

    const address = /https:\/\/swapi.co\/api\/planets/[0-9]/

    beforeEach(()=>{
        moxios.install()
        moxios.stubRequest(
            address,
            {
                status: 200,
                response: mockPlanet
            }
        )
    })

    afterEach(()=>{
        moxios.uninstall()
    })

    it('Fetch planet on click',()=>{

        wrapped = mount(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <App/>
            </Provider>, options
        ) 

        wrapped.find('.button-get-planet').first().simulate('click')
        wrapped.update()

       // What should I test here?
   })
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are few gotchas there:

1. `redux-mock-store` [does not run](https://github.com/dmitry-zaets/redux-mock-store) reducer. To test real reducer and real actions(otherwise your `axios`'s mock will never be applied to component) you need using real store instead.
2. since your `axios` mocks are Promise-based you need either `moxios.wait` or `setTimeout()`/`await <anything>` before running check. Otherwise Promise will not be fullfilled by time you try to validate something.
3. And you actually don't need `wrapper.update()` since it will run by redux once you handle items #1 and #2

In your test you have to verify your component looks like expected after data is loaded successfully.

```
// simulate click
// check some "Loader" is displayed if expected
await Promise.resolve(); // just to flush microtasks queue - or use moxios.wait()
// check real data is rendered accordingly
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Can you give me some code examples?

Comment: @MichaelFernandes may you provide how does your component _render_ that planets? and what exact happens on clicking `'.button-get-planet'` button?

Comment: here is my public repository: https://github.com/mfazevedo/StarWarsPlanets

This file contains the button click function: https://github.com/mfazevedo/StarWarsPlanets/blob/master/src/components/App.js

Comment: Now I'm using the real store, and I don't see the render updates:

`it('Fetch planet on click',(done)=>{

    wrapped = mount(
        <Root>
            <App activePlanet = {initialPlanet}/>
        </Root>, options
    ) 

    wrapped.find('.button-get-planet').first().simulate('click')

    moxios.wait(()=>{
        wrapped.update()
        console.log('>>>', wrapped.text())

        //expected
        
        done()
    })
})`